# Generic repositories/services in a specific layer to use in many projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, simple-injector

I have many applications that use generic repository and generic services. These applications was developed by different developers and each project has different methods signatures, for example: GetAll or ReturnAll, Create or Add etc.
I trying to build a generic repository and services layer for all applications to ensure code standard and avoid create a generic repository and service layer for new applications.

When I execute the project I get the simple injector error:

> The supplied type `BaseService<TEntity, TContext>` contains unresolvable type arguments. The type would never be resolved and is therefore not suited to be used.
>   Parameter name: implementationType

BaseService class:

```
public class BaseService<TEntity, TContext> : IBaseService<TEntity, DbContext> where TEntity : class where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected IBaseRepository<TEntity, TContext> _baseRepository;

    public BaseService(IBaseRepository<TEntity, TContext> baseRepository)
    {
        _baseRepository = baseRepository;
    }

    public virtual void Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            _baseRepository.Create(entity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Create(IList<TEntity> entities)
    {
        try
        {
            _baseRepository.Create(entities);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Base Repository class:

```
public class BaseRepository<Entity, TContext> : IDisposable, IBaseRepository<Entity, TContext> where Entity : class where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly TContext _context;

    public BaseRepository(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Add(Entity obj)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Set<Entity>().Add(obj);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error to add", ex);
        }
    }

    public void Add(IList<Entity> list)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Set<Entity>().AddRange(list);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error to add", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation in a repository:

```
public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User, DbContext>, IUserRepository
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;
    public UserRepository(MyContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

Registering in bootstrapper class:

```
container.Register(typeof(IBaseRepository<,>), (typeof(BaseRepository<,>)), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

container.Register(typeof(IBaseService<,>), (typeof(BaseService<,>)), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<IUserService, UserService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<MyContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register(typeof(IBaseService<,>), (typeof(BaseService<,>)), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

I build an example project with the same structure of the project that I work in with the same error. [Link to project in GitHub](https://github.com/tiagocrizanto/GenericLayers)

Answer (score 0):

Even though the error message is clear, it's easy to miss what's going wrong. The message says:

> The supplied type BaseService contains unresolvable type arguments.

This means that either one of the type arguments (i.e. `TEntity` or `TContext`) can't be mapped to the supplied interface. If we look at the definition of `BaseService<TEntity, TContext>` we can see why:

```
public class BaseService<TEntity, TContext> : IBaseService<TEntity, DbContext>
```

See how this class implements `IBaseService<TEntity, DbContext>` instead of `BaseService<TEntity, TContext>`. In other words, `TContext` is not mapped.

You should therefore change your implementation to the following:

```
public class BaseService<TEntity, TContext> : IBaseService<TEntity, TContext>
```

Comment: And if you are wondering why it took so long to get an answer, that's because your question has way too many details. If you reduce your next question to the [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the response time will be much quicker. In this case, you could have reduced your question to 6 lines of code, which might have even let you to figuring out what was going wrong yourself.

Comment: Hi Steven. Thanks for your answer. I change the code of baseservice but I still get the same erros. I think I'm making a mistake when in bootstraper register class and the baserepository can't infer the EF context type. I tried build a "minimal and readable" question, so I created a repository in git where it's possible to reproduce the same problem.

Comment: Hi Tiago, like many others on Stackoverflow that are trying to help, I'm quite a busy man, so I haven't got the time to browse through the complete project you put online. That project is certainly not the "minimal, verifiable example" I am referring to. As I said, I was able to reproduce your original problem with 8 lines of code. My suggestion is that you try to produce such small running program again with your new problem. Stackoverflow expects you to post that code on Stackoverflow itself. I'm happy to take a look at 10 to 20 lines of code, but certainly not a 1400+ line example project.